# How can I make a custom std::array like class modify values at an index?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to recreate the std::array class in a very simple way. (I also called it vector, as I feel that makes more sense in a namespace called `maths`). (of course, this isn't complete yet).

here is the vector class.

```cpp
namespace maths {
    ...
    template <typename T, int dims>
    class vector {
    private:
        T arr[dims];
    public:
        int operator[](int idx) {
            return arr[idx];
        }
    
        int dimensions() {
            return dims;
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

I can do this so far:

```cpp
maths::vector<int, 2> test;
std::cout << test[0] << std::endl;
```

I am wondering how I can get this to work the other way (ie. modifying the value at the index, rather than only reading from it):

```cpp
int random_int = 100;
test[0] = random_int;
```

Right now, I am thinking about operator overloading, however, I do not know how I can mix operator overloading
(for example how to mix [] and =.)

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Return a reference, `int& operator[](int idx)`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 This worked! Sorry that this was such a beginner question. Could you make this into an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you'd need the known quadruplication to be complete.

```
template <typename T, unsigned dims>
class vector {
private:
    T arr[dims];
public:
    constexpr T const&  operator[](unsigned idx) const& {
        return arr[idx];
    }
    constexpr T& operator[](unsigned idx) & {
        return arr[idx];
    }
    constexpr T const&& operator[]( unsigned idx ) const&& {
        return arr[idx];
    }
    constexpr T&& operator []( unsigned idx ) && {
        return arr[idx];
    }

    constexpr unsigned dimensions() const {
        return dims;
    }
};
```

There is a propostal for C++23 to eliminate the need for all this duplication.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html